# converting xml to hash @ desired depth in perl

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I am trying to get a hash {key, value} pair of the desired node given the query element-name.

The following perl code is an attempt to get an output which can be printed as follows:

```
p $error_hash->{'errorCode'}
0
p $error_hash->{'errorMsg'}
"get device list successfully"
```

Appreciate your help in fixing the missing logic.

The code given here prints the "value" only. Even if I were to use `$xml_hash`, I have to prune the first three nodes manually before I get the desired hash.

Thanks,
Seeking that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::Hash;

my $xml = do {local $/;  < DATA > };
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_string($xml);

my $xpath="//getDeviceResponse";

my $xml_converter = XML::Hash->new();
my $xml_hash = $xml_converter->fromXMLStringtoHash($xml);

my (%errmsg) = "";
my (%devinfo) = "";

sub get_value {
    my $elem = $_[0];

    my $query="$xpath";
    foreach my $errorMsg ($doc->findnodes($query)) {
        my ($title) = $errorMsg->findnodes($elem);
        print $title->to_literal;
    }
}

get_value "errorMsg";    
get_value "deviceInfo";

__DATA__
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ns1="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array"
        xmlns:ns3="http://r200806.ws.abc.com/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <getDeviceResponse>
                        <errorMsg>
                                <errorCode>0</errorCode>
                                <errorMsg>get device list successfully&#xA;</errorMsg>
                        </errorMsg>
                        <deviceInfo>
                                <devId>139</devId>
                                <firmware>abc</firmware>
                                <firmwareVersion>5.0</firmwareVersion>
                                <buildNum>208</buildNum>
                                <description></description>
                                <hostname>puppet</hostname>
                                <platform>puppetlabs</platform>
                                <sn>abc1234</sn>
                                <ip>172.168.210.2</ip>
                        </deviceInfo>
                </getDeviceResponse>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines produce a warning on my system:

```
my (%errmsg) = "";
my (%devinfo) = "";
```

You seem more accustomed to hashes than xpath, so I'll give you an example using those:

```
my $getDeviceResponse_hash = $xml_hash->{'SOAP-ENV:Envelope'}{'SOAP-ENV:Body'}{'getDeviceResponse'};
my $errorMsg_hash = $getDeviceResponse_hash->{'errorMsg'};
print $errorMsg_hash->{'errorMsg'}{'text'};
print $errorMsg_hash->{'errorCode'}{'text'};
```

You can always check the structure of those hashes like so:

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
print Dumper($errorMsg_hash);
```

Comment: The two lines compile. There's just an "odd number of elements in hash" warning.

Comment: @SlavenRezic Quite right. I'm a little surprised they run at all, but that's neither here nor there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `XML::Twig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA ); 
my %hash = map { $_ -> tag => $_ -> trimmed_text } $twig -> findnodes ( '//getDeviceResponse/errorMsg', 0) -> children;
print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ns1="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array"
        xmlns:ns3="http://r200806.ws.abc.com/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <getDeviceResponse>
                        <errorMsg>
                                <errorCode>0</errorCode>
                                <errorMsg>get device list successfully&#xA;</errorMsg>
                        </errorMsg>
                        <deviceInfo>
                                <devId>139</devId>
                                <firmware>abc</firmware>
                                <firmwareVersion>5.0</firmwareVersion>
                                <buildNum>208</buildNum>
                                <description></description>
                                <hostname>puppet</hostname>
                                <platform>puppetlabs</platform>
                                <sn>abc1234</sn>
                                <ip>172.168.210.2</ip>
                        </deviceInfo>
                </getDeviceResponse>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'errorMsg' => 'get device list successfully',
          'errorCode' => '0'
        };
```

So you can:

```
print $hash{$errorMsg},"\n";
```

Note - this only gets the first (only) instance of 'errorMsg' in a file. You could do multiple easily enough, but you'd need to change your data structure slightly, because they keys would clash.